# how to fix Braintree not passing "device_data" with clint js?

Tags: braintree, braintree-data

I want to use user `"device_data"` with braintree js client, but the the data not passed and `$_POST['device_data']` is valid method!
I try this on sandbox! does it differ on production environment?

here are my codes!

```
<div style="max-width:300px; margin:20px auto;">
    <form id="checkout" method="post" action="patch/to/checkout">
        <div id="payment-form"></div>
        <input type="submit" value="Pay" />
    </form>
</div>
<script src="https://js.braintreegateway.com/v2/braintree.js"></script>
<script>
var clientToken = "clientTokenFromPHP";
braintree.setup(clientToken, "dropin", {
    dataCollector: {
        kount: {environment: 'sandbox'},
        paypal: true
    },
    onReady: function (braintreeInstance) {
        braintreeInstance.deviceData;
    },
    container: "payment-form",

});
</script>
```

i try to echo the `$_POST['device_data']` on checkout page but it was undefined!
how can i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://support.braintreepayments.com).</sub>

This is a known issue with braintree.js when trying to use `deviceData` and dropin. I would follow the [github issue](https://github.com/braintree/braintree-web/issues/114) for updates on the matter.

Comment: i include  braintree-2.17.5.min.js but it doesn't fix the problem!

Comment: could you please gimme a working sample for both PayPal and credit card.

Comment: 2.17.5 hasn't fixed the issue, it is still being worked on. An alternative would be to use [Hosted Fields](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/hosted-fields/overview). You would have to do your own styling, but it is presently working with `deviceData`.

Comment: I think we should stamp a very very Big BETA on Braintree.  triy this but not work for me! and something more how can i hide card fields if user choose pay with PayPal? Braintree documents are so so Concise and unclear.